# Dotnet restore error

Tags: .net, dnx, .net-core

I just install dotnet-win-x64.latest.msi on my win7.
I am trying to create a new project, but it fails when I use "dotnet restore" command, so is "dotnet run". see as below. What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with dotnet - you need to install dotnet to a folder without whitespaces. See these two github issues for more details:

- [dotnet restore fails if CLI is installed in a path with spaces](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/911)
- [Restore of DotNet.exe is not working](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/948)

Comment: It works after reinstalled to path without spaces, many thanks.